# strcpy source is not displayed

Tags: c++, strcpy

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    char a[]="one string",b[]="twostrings";
     strcpy (a,b);

    cout<<"A="<<a;
    cout<<endl<<"B="<<b<<endl;
}
```

a and b are equal after displaying them ,but if I put a space like this `b[]="two strings"`, and then cout b ,it  shows b as blank,why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because with the space, the `a[]` buffer isn't large enough to hold a copy of `b`, and your attempt to make it do so corrupts the stack yielding undefined behaviour.  Anything may happen, but very likely in your case it's overwriting the first byte of the next variable (i.e. `b`) with the terminating `NUL` such that `b` appears empty.

To spell it out:

```
a          b
one string0two strings0  // original content 0=NUL
two strings0wo strings0  // after copy
```

Obligatory tip: use `std::string` whenever you can.